# Can this code be optimized more?

Tags: python, optimization, logic

The Question was:

There is a rail road to different towns from one town. It is considered that the 
rail road is a one way because of budgetary issues. If there is city A and it has 
cities B and C cities connected by rail roads, it is not mandatory that A has 
direct rail road to both B and C. The route to C from A can be A to B and then B 
to C. The above scenario is depicted as a graph. The nodes are the towns and 
edges are the distances between them.
The input given will be a graph and also the route to towns. The output must be the total rail road distance between the towns and if no route exists, it must say 'No Route exists'.

```
Input: AB5, BC2, CD3, BE4
Input: A-B-E
Input: A-C-E
Output: 9
Output: No Route Exists
```

My code is:

```
print "Welcome to the total path calculation program"
n=1
inp=1
graph=dict()
while(n==1):
 print "Enter the connection:"
 x=raw_input()
 new={x[0]:{x[1]:x[2]}}
 graph.update(new)
 print "Do you want to enter another connection?"
 y=raw_input()
 if y=='y':
   n=1
 else:
   n=0

while(inp):
 print "Now enter the connection to find the total cost:"
 x=raw_input()
 try:
    t=int(graph[x[0]][x[2]])+int(graph[x[2]][x[4]])
    print "The total cost is %d" %(t)
 except KeyError:
    print "No route exists"
 print "Do you want to find cost for more connections?"
 x=raw_input()
 if x=='y':
    inp=1
 else:
    inp=0
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem might help

Comment: @akonsu I dont want shortest path... I just want total path..

Comment: then what do you mean by "optimized"?

Comment: It can be optimized more for correctness.

Comment: @sundar what is the "total path"?

Comment: "Optimized more for correctness"... you mean debugged? 9_9

Comment: If your code works but you want to improve it, the question probably belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Thanks... Just heard CodeReview now... I will ask my optimization of codings there..

Comment: @akonsu for example A-B-E means total path= A-B cost + B-E cost

Comment: @Ant Optimized I refer to Optimization in logic...

Comment: @2rs2ts Yeah.... more simpler in debugging and logic..

Comment: @sundar, suppose you have a circular road and towns are located on the circle. To me it seems that it makes sense to discuss only the shortest path between two towns. I still do not see what "total path" is. Your problem definition is vague.

Comment: @akonsu If there are circular roads, then the question does not specify to find the shortest path.. It needs total path.. not necessary the shortest one..

Comment: @sundar you are *vastly* misunderstanding how a shortest path algorithm works.

Answer (score 1):

Couple quick things, when you want to run an infinite loop, and have it break on a specific event, there's no need to declare and modify a variable strictly for this purpose.
You can simply start your while loops like this

```
while True:
```

and end them like this

```
y=raw_input()
if y.lower() !='y':
    break
```

Notice the `.lower` at the end of the variable.  This will force user input to lower case, so your check will catch both "Y" and "y", which may be helpful.

Comment: That needs to be `y.lower()`.

Comment: I personally think this is questionable. As a layman, I think that it is easier to prove that a `while` loop with a variable terminates, than a loop with `True` and a `break`.

Comment: @Andenthal Even this is also much simpler!!!                                                           while(True):
 print "inside the loop"
 y=raw_input()
 if y!='y':
     break